# HDRI won't show on render mode

Tags: hdri

HDRI I set wouldn't show on any view mode.
It just comes up all black or orange but it's supposed show buildings.
What I 've already checked are below.

・Environment texture is used (not the image texture) on the shader node
・transparent mode is OFF
・HDRI file is exr type

[image]

Comment: Maybe switch to Perspective mode (numpad 5 key), if it's not the problem please pack your image and share your file

Comment: @moonboots It worked! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You won't see the HDRI in *Orthographic* view, switch to *Perspective* view (numpad <kbd>5</kbd>)